# php, proc_open how pass multiple arguments

Tags: php, python

I am writing php code which will work under *nix systems. I need to call a python script with 5 arguments inside php code. Some of arguments
are user input so there could be any characters. I cannot figure out how pass arguments to a script. How would I separate arguments?. For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880589/multiple-input-with-proc-open) you separate by end of line character, but in my arguments could be anything written by users. How to pass such arguments? any ideas?

EDIT:
I have idea of putting escape character in each quotes symbols ' or " before
passing arguments, on the other end I will get rid of escape character. Does json encoding do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want is `escapeshellcmd()`:

```
$arg1 = escapeshellarg($input1);
$arg2 = "foo";
$arg3 = escapeshellarg($input3);
$arg4 = "bar";
$arg5 = escapeshellarg("a string containing spaces and other *special* characters");
$proc = proc_open("python_prog $arg1 $arg2 $arg3 $arg4 $arg5", ...);
```

In the other thread, the program didn't take any arguments, the newlines were being used to separate items on standard input.

Comment: Actually, `escapeshellcmd` is supposed to be used with command only (`escapeshellcmd("/path/to/bin");`). For argument escaping, use `escapeshellarg` instead, (`escapeshellarg("argument");`).

Answer (score 1):

You're basically executing a command on the command prompt; you might want to familiarize yourself with a command prompt first.

Parameters are separated by spaces.  So if your inputs have spaces in them, you have to put quotes around these inputs (I suggest single quotes; using a double quote will lead to environment variables being expanded, among other things).

So basically, you have to escape all the single quotes, line breaks, and carriage returns in your inputs, surround each of them with single quotes and append them to the command.

**Warning:** Security-wise, this whole thing is very problematic.  If your escape mechanism is not bullet-proof, anyone would be able to execute a command on your server.

An alternate answer would be to write the inputs into a temporary file, and read from this file in your python script.  If you have control over this script, I would strongly suggest you to do that.

Comment: why do I need escape spaces? I can escape all qoutes and put quotes to separate arguments, this way everything between quotes would be considered as one argument. Could you give example what imput can harm such approach?

Comment: no need to escape spaces; given Barmar's answer you don't need to worry about it anyway.